# phpDom XPath to get self html content?

Tags: html, xpath, element, domdocument

Let's say, inside StudentList.html got this data

---

```
<div class="tableHeader">
<div class="header">
<div class="header-item">Name</div>
<div class="header-item">ID</div>
<div class="header-item">Email</div>
</div>

<div class="studentRow"></div>
```

---

Then I execute:

```
$dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$str = file_get_contents("StudentList.html");
if ($dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($str, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8')) == true) {
    $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
    $nodeList = $xpath->query("//div[@class='tableHeader']");
    $node = $nodeList->item(0);
    echo "<p>" . $node->nodeValue . "</p>";     
}
```

but above method is to get the value inside only, not what I want...

What I want is getting full block html content when this class block matched.

so it should return content below when I perform echo

```
<div class="tableHeader">
<div class="header">
<div class="header-item">Name</div>
<div class="header-item">ID</div>
<div class="header-item">Email</div>
</div>
```

any way?

Comment: just found the answer, the saveXML is the key to get full html content including itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to get full html including self

```
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$div = $xpath->query("//div[@class='tableHeader']");
$div = $div->item(0);
$content= $dom->saveXML($div);
echo $content;
```